# Dynamic Feature Module with Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, androidx, dynamic-feature-module

I am a Native Android Developer and I was learning Dynamic Feature Module from [here](https://medium.com/@kris1837/how-to-start-activity-from-dynamic-feature-module-on-android-75a55d782e6a) 
But I also work with flutter. So, is this feature available in flutter?

Comment: DFM is  heavy reliance on reflections and dart dont use relfection so i doubt

Answer (score 2):

"UPDATE" - Flutter's [Deffered-Components](https://docs.flutter.dev/perf/deferred-components) is meant for dynamic feature modules. It build apps that can download additional Dart code and assets at runtime.

OLD Reply - Flutter supports Android App Bundles too (just like for Android App using Java/Kotlin) as mentioned [here](https://docs.codemagic.io/building/building-android-app-bundles/) and this [Pull request](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/24440). App bundles allows Dynamic feature module support, hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

It is not but flutter now has ability to add flutter to existing android app which you can use for that case, I.e build all submodule in flutter and add or load them in a native app, I hope you got an idea.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like work is being done to support Dyanmic Features in Flutter in the future.
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/commit/a76bb1a08e3d22ea73a5f8005e6e46925ee938c3

As of this time, support for Dynamic Features has not been announced.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if a flutter functionality could be wrapped in a dynamic feature module. https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Add-Flutter-to-existing-apps